# unresolved import 'models' Python Application

Tags: python, import

I've been butting my head trying to figure out why python isn't importing my apps.
Im new at coding so I don't understand what im doing wrong, please help.
Im using windows and python3.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkXMY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using relative imports.

```py
from .models import stuff
```

Comment: Im now getting an error when I run my app

Comment: Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: While importing "app", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\eftn\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\eftn\iflask\asses_2\databases\databases\playlist-app\app.py", line 4, in <module>  
    from .models import db, connect_db, Playlist, Song, PlaylistSong
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: Make sure you have an `__init__.py` file somewhere in the folder with you models so python recognizes your app as a package. The `___init__.py` file can be empty.